# Convert flat data into a hierarchical python list

Tags: python, hierarchical

I have a data model from my database. This is a flat python list sorted by left values.

```
>     id    name        left    right
>     1 Beginning   1   6
>     2 FOO     2   5
>     3 BAR     3   4
>     4 Programming 6   13
>     5 Python      7   8
>     7 C#      9   12
>     8 XNA     10  11
>     6 About       14  15
```

I would like to compute this into a hierarchical python list, that in turn will be converted to HTML/XML as a unordered list. The python list with be a lists within lists.

Example

```
categories = [
   ["programming", [
                      ["Python", ["pygame"]],
                      ["C#", ["XNA"]],
                   ]
   ],
   ["FOO", [
               ["BAR"]
           ]
   ],
]
```

Comment: Please give a self-consistent example of input and output -- your example output has a "pygame" entry that's **nowhere** on your example input, how could any program possibly make it up?!

Comment: you said "sorted by left values", doesn't seem to be, neither by left most column (id), anyway how is the relation between rows represented, otherwise there is no way to construct a nested list

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified pre-order tree traversal.

http://www.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database/

So the input looks like this, a list of dictionaries.

```
dbrows = [
   {'title': 'Food', 'lft': 1, 'rgt': 18},
   {'title': 'Fruit', 'lft': 2, 'rgt': 11},
   #etc... etc... from the linked article.
]
```

Using the fruit input from the linked article. This is what I want, sorted as a python list.

```
tree = [
        ['Food', [
             ['Fruit', [
                   ['Red', ['Cherry', 'Strawberry']],
                   ['Yellow', ['Banana']],
             ]],
             ['Meat', [
                   ['Beef', 'Pork']
             ]],
        ]],
]
```